# Classifier which guesses highest frequency class from training data

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a specific name for a machine learning classifier which *always* guesses the class which had the highest frequency in the training data?

I am using this model as a baseline, and would like to refer to it by its proper name.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes referred to as the *base model*, since, at least as far as accuracy is concerned, any other model should do better or else why bother. This is of course not true when one wants a more balanced model that hits all the categories.

Answer (score 1):

It's a ZeroR classifier. It's the simplest classification method which ignores all attributes (variables) in the prediction model and relies solely on target variable. It is also implemented in Weka (`weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR`).